# Ansible adhoc command execute with sudo

Tags: linux, ansible, operations-orchestration

I need execute ansible adhoc command.

```
$ ansible somehost -m command -a "cat /etc/passwd"-u someuser --ask-sudo-pass
```

I have an user account (someuser) with `sudo` privilege. Usually I became root  `sudo su -`.

How to use adhoc command with `sudo su -` ?

ansible version is 2.0.0.2

Comment: try simply adding `--sudo` to that commandline. If that works I'll explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct ansible command is

> ansible all -m command -a "docker info"  -u myuser --become-user root
>   --ask-pass --ask-become-pass

Answer (score 6):

For Ansible version 1.9 or newer you need to use `--ask-become-pass` instead. For older versions `--ask-sudo-pass` should work.

[Become (Privilege Escalation)](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html)

> Before 1.9 Ansible mostly allowed the use of *sudo* and a limited use of
>   *su* to allow a login/remote user to become a different user and execute
>   tasks, create resources with the 2nd user’s permissions. As of 1.9
>   *become* supersedes the old sudo/su, while still being backwards
>   compatible. This new system also makes it easier to add other
>   privilege escalation tools like *pbrun* (Powerbroker), *pfexec*, *dzdo*
>   (Centrify), and others.

Comment: doesn't work.
Permission denied.

currently code is 

ansible all -m command -a "docker info"  -u mysuser --ask-pass --ask-become-pass -vvv

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev, well your answer shows that it does. In my answer I haven't given you any command to try rahter pointed you to the correct option that needs to be used and the reference to it.

Answer (score 6):

If you have SSH keys shared to your servers in your inventory and you're going to want to `sudo` to root, you can further reduce the command to this:

```
$ ansible all -m command -a "docker info" -u myuser --become --ask-become-pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ad-hoc and when I got into this problem, adding `-b --become-user ANSIBLE_USER` to my command fixes my problem. example:

```
ansible all  -m file -a "path=/etc/s.text state=touch" -b --become-user ansadmin
```

### **Of course, before this, I had given Sudo access to the user**

If you give Sudo access to your user, you can write like this :

```
ansible all  -m file -a "path=/var/s.text state=touch"  -b --become-user root
```